# How to limit collapse content width on bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to limit the width of the div content below my collapse button.
Right now the content (the lorem on the code example below) has a width exceeding the button width.

How can I limit the content's width so that it is at most as wide as the button like shown in the img below?

I have tried adding `max-width: 75%;` into the content div (class `collapse`), but when I added that, it messed up the layout and it looks like the bottom-most screenshot.

Desired:

[image: Desired result]

Got this when I added `max-width: 75%`:

[image: wrong-alignment]
Code:

```
<div class='text-center'>
  <div class="row main">
    <div class="center-block">
       <div>

         <a class="btn btn-primary custom-btn custom" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
           Link with href
         </a>

         <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
           <div class="card card-block">
             Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life   accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
             Turkey pastrami spare ribs flank tongue, pork chop drumstick sirloin biltong frankfurter. Flank ball tip sirloin, sausage short loin leberkas short ribs tenderloin boudin. Alcatra ribeye porchetta ball tip pig picanha filet mignon kielbasa fatback jowl kevin. Short ribs pork chop tri-tip fatback kielbasa jowl ham brisket biltong cow beef tail venison. Flank boudin pork loin beef ribs venison kielbasa brisket biltong meatloaf. Pig hamburger beef ribs, pork belly beef turducken tongue spare ribs drumstick kevin jerky tail strip steak prosciutto bacon.

           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.custom-btn {
  background-color: #7CA46E;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.custom {
  width: 75%;
  min-width: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify the `display` value of the collapse target to `inline-block` when it is showing.

Bootstrap's collapse functionality sets the `display` of the collapse target to `block` when not collapsed which causes it to be laid out differently from the collapse trigger (the `a.btn` element). You can override this value with your own CSS.

```css
.custom-btn {
  background-color: #7CA46E;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.custom,
#collapseExample.in,
#collapseExample.collapsing {
  width: 75%;
  min-width: 400px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class='text-center'>
  <div class="row main">
    <div class="center-block">
      <div>

        <a class="btn btn-primary custom-btn custom" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
           Link with href
        </a>

        <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
          <div class="card card-block">
            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Turkey pastrami spare ribs flank tongue, pork chop drumstick
            sirloin biltong frankfurter. Flank ball tip sirloin, sausage short loin leberkas short ribs tenderloin boudin. Alcatra ribeye porchetta ball tip pig picanha filet mignon kielbasa fatback jowl kevin. Short ribs pork chop tri-tip fatback kielbasa
            jowl ham brisket biltong cow beef tail venison. Flank boudin pork loin beef ribs venison kielbasa brisket biltong meatloaf. Pig hamburger beef ribs, pork belly beef turducken tongue spare ribs drumstick kevin jerky tail strip steak prosciutto
            bacon.

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```